# How do I save areas of an Inkscape file to separate SVG files?

Tags: image-processing, inkscape, svg

I am working on making window buttons for a [Unity 7 theme](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming) using Inkscape. The file I have uses a 7x4 grid, with each grid space 19px square and containing a single button image. Multiple layers are used for the button backgrounds, icons, state effects, etc. Basically, I now have each of the intended button images laid out on the same grid side-by-side.

What I can't figure out / find information for online is how to split this single SVG image up into multiple smaller files, one for each individual button image. I would need each one to contain its respective 19px by 19px area, and be in both SVG and PNG format.

The PNG part I could probably do by hand using the **Export PNG image** menu option, picking a different area of the image to export each time. However, I have no idea how I could get the separate SVG images, which is important because SVG is what Unity prefers to display. Everything I've looked at online is for separating each layer into a separate file, which is not what I'm looking for here.

So, how do I get my separate SVGs from this one larger image? An automated solution would be preferable to save time actually doing it.

Comment: As a non-automated way, you can use your mouse to select the elements you want in the area you want, then do a ctrl-c, ctrl-n, ctrl-v and resize the page, right? Just wanted to make sure I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @AmirH.Sadoughi Yes, this manual method works as well (have to also center the pasted objects in the page after resizing). Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier. However, if you have a script which can automate this, that'd be even better, as I'd have to repeat this 28 times.

Comment: Well, I haven't used inkscape in a while now, I say looking at the macros might be a good place to start: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkscape/macrogoodness

Comment: And hey this script seems to be promising: https://github.com/berteh/svg-objects-export again, I have not used it unfortunately.